# Parse git log by modified files

Tags: command-line, git, grep, text-processing

I have been told to make git messages for each modified file all one line so I can use grep to find all changes to that file.  For instance:

```
$git commit -a
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h - 1) change1 , 2) change2, etc......

$git log | grep path/to/file.cpp/.h
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h - 1) change1 , 2) change2, etc......
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h - 1) change1 , 2) change2, etc......
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h - 1) change1 , 2) change2, etc......
```

That's great, but then the actual line is harder to read because it either runs off the screen or wraps and wraps and wraps.

If I want to make messages like this:

```
$git commit -a
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h 
               1) change1 
               2) change2
               etc......
```

is there a good way to then use grep or cut or some other tool to get a readout like

```
$git log | grep path/to/file.cpp/.h
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h 
               1) change1 
               2) change2
               etc......
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h 
               1) change1 
               2) change2
               etc......
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h 
               1) change1 
               2) change2
               etc......
```

Comment: just post the output of `git log` in your question and also the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output of `grep` command shows like this,

```
$ git log | grep path/to/file.cpp/.h
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h - 1) change1 , 2) change2, etc......
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h - 1) change1 , 2) change2, etc......
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h - 1) change1 , 2) change2, etc......
```

Then you can pipe it to the below awk command to produce the desired output,

```
git log | grep path/to/file.cpp/.h | awk -v RS='[-,]' '{print}'
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat aa
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h - 1) change1 , 2) change2, etc......
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h - 1) change1 , 2) change2, etc......
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h - 1) change1 , 2) change2, etc......

$ awk -v RS='[-,]' '{print}' aa
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h 
 1) change1 
 2) change2
 etc......
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h 
 1) change1 
 2) change2
 etc......
     modified: path/to/file.cpp/.h 
 1) change1 
 2) change2
 etc......
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash Raj.  I guess it makes sense to just deal with initially writing the commit message for a file all on one line, then processing it after.